# How can I bind data to a specifc location in knockoutjs?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

How can I bind "ActiveSellers" count with the value of "Description" using knockout?

```
<div class="detailProductPrice">
"Description"
<a class="compare comparea" data-bind="attr: {'href': '/product/'+ FolderName}"   target="_top">COMPARE PRICE</a> 
from "ActiveSellers" sellers
</div>
```

The "Description" section is html. "ActiveSellers" is a Number.

Comment: Show your view-model.

Comment: With the `html` binding for `Description` and the `text` binding for `ActiveSellers`?

Comment: @GôTô, how? that div contains a anchor. how to bind"Description" html at that position?

Comment: @haim770 i pulled that data from webservice and fill observablearray by using this Code    $(JSON.parse(data.d)).each(function (index, element) {
                            self.ProductList.push(element);

                        });

Comment: Use a containerless element http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/text-binding.html#note-3-using-text-without-a-container-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with a [containerless element](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/text-binding.html#note-3-using-text-without-a-container-element):

```
<div class="detailProductPrice">
    <!--ko html: Description--><!--/ko-->
    <a class="compare comparea" 
       data-bind="attr: {'href': '/product/'+ FolderName}"
       target="_top">COMPARE PRICE</a> 
    from <!--ko text: ActiveSellers--><!--/ko--> sellers
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either add an empty span element:

```
<div class="detailProductPrice">
<span data-bind="html: Description"></span>
<a class="compare comparea" data-bind="attr: {'href': '/product/'+ FolderName}"       target="_top">COMPARE PRICE</a> 
<span data-bind="text: ActiveSellers"></span>
</div>
```

or use KO's bindings without a container element

```
<div class="detailProductPrice">
<!--ko html: Description--><!--/ko-->
<a class="compare comparea" data-bind="attr: {'href': '/product/'+ FolderName}"       target="_top">COMPARE PRICE</a> 
<!--ko text: ActiveSellers--><!--/ko-->
</div>
```

Comment: That's just plain plagiarism! :)

Comment: If it makes you feel any better @GôTô, I only saw your answer after my edit :)